# Does Symfony 6.2 and Twig 3.x support linking to HTML id attributes on the same page?

Tags: symfony

I spent some time reading through Symfony 6.x and Twig 3.x docs. I couldn't find anything about linking to HTML id attributes via the twig templating engine to accomplish smooth scrolling on the same-page.

from what I understand, I need to create a route attribute/annotation that maps to the classes controller/method. doing so will require a new page to be created.

You can also create parameters for your route attribute/annotation such as a {slug} that can be passed as a argument via the controller/method. Doing this will allow you to use the URL param as a variable. This method also requires you to link to another page.

Is there a way to use Symfony 6.2 & Twig 3.x and link to html id attributes on the same page. Is there a section on the docs I overlooked... I'm all out of ideas... you're help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: An in-page link is just an `href` pointing to a URL with an `#` that references an `id` or `name` attribute. These are simple HTML things, how do you want Symfony to help you? If one “page” (URL) has two named destinations, the Symfony route would be the same, only the fragment would change. If the fragments are dynamic, I’d expect them to be data-bound in some way, and you could just loop over them and concatenate them somehow

Comment: When routing, you can dynamically access the fragment via the `_fragment` special parameter: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#special-parameters

Comment: @ChrisHaas, thanks for the response. I'd also like to add. the navigation menu is in two states. desktop view and mobile view. when in desktop view I use # to route to the desired section of the page. however, when I'm in mobile view and need to return to the home page and smooth scroll to the desired section of the homepage. the URL will remain in that current state and the new request will just stack on top. I tried passing a slug through the controller/method and using str_replace(). It didn't work.